# Acomodar el contador en python

Tags: python

estoy intentando imprimir en consola de Python junto con el número de movimientos, ejemplo:
Ingreso el número de 2 discos

```
1 .- Mover el Disco 1 de la Torre A a la Torre B
2 .- Mover el Disco 2 de la Torre A a la Torre C
3 .- Mover el Disco 1 de la Torre B a la Torre C
```

Este es mi código en Python:

```
contador = 1
discos = int(input("Dame el número de discos: "))

if discos > 0:
    while contador <= 2**discos-1:
        contador = contador + 1
else:
    print("ENTONCES NO HAY DISCOS!!!")

def Torre_Hanoi(n, TorreOrigen="A", TorreAuxiliar="B", TorreDestino="C"):
    if n > 0:
        Torre_Hanoi(n - 1, TorreOrigen, TorreDestino, TorreAuxiliar)
        fila = f"{contador} .- Mover el Disco {n} de la Torre {TorreOrigen} a la Torre {TorreDestino}"
        print(fila)
        Torre_Hanoi(n - 1, TorreAuxiliar, TorreOrigen, TorreDestino)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Torre_Hanoi(discos)
```

pero me imprime en la consola:

```
4 .- Mover el Disco 1 de la Torre A a la Torre B
4 .- Mover el Disco 2 de la Torre A a la Torre C
4 .- Mover el Disco 1 de la Torre B a la Torre C
```

Comment: Debes agregar que trabas estás teniendo para lograr lo que intentas, solo dices lo que quieres hacer pero no explicas que errores/impedimentos tienes

Comment: Esta bien, lo que pasa es que soy nuevo aquí en este sitio para aclarar dudas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás fijando el valor de `contador` antes de empezar a mover los discos:

```
contador = 1
discos = int(input("Dame el número de discos: "))

if discos > 0:
    while contador <= 2**discos-1:
        contador = contador + 1
else:
    print("ENTONCES NO HAY DISCOS!!!")
```

No alcanzo a entender la razón del ciclo `while` ...

La variable `contador` tienes que actualizarla luego de imprimir cada movimiento. Como es una variable externa a la función, tienes que declararla `global`.

El código corregido es:

```
contador = 1
discos = int(input("Dame el número de discos: "))

def Torre_Hanoi(n, TorreOrigen="A", TorreAuxiliar="B", TorreDestino="C"):
    global contador
    if n > 0:
        Torre_Hanoi(n - 1, TorreOrigen, TorreDestino, TorreAuxiliar)
        fila = f"{contador} .- Mover el Disco {n} de la Torre {TorreOrigen} a la Torre {TorreDestino}"
        contador += 1
        print(fila)
        Torre_Hanoi(n - 1, TorreAuxiliar, TorreOrigen, TorreDestino)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Torre_Hanoi(discos)
```

produce:

```
Dame el número de discos: 3
1 .- Mover el Disco 1 de la Torre A a la Torre C
2 .- Mover el Disco 2 de la Torre A a la Torre B
3 .- Mover el Disco 1 de la Torre C a la Torre B
4 .- Mover el Disco 3 de la Torre A a la Torre C
5 .- Mover el Disco 1 de la Torre B a la Torre A
6 .- Mover el Disco 2 de la Torre B a la Torre C
7 .- Mover el Disco 1 de la Torre A a la Torre C
```